# Suppose $A$ is a $ 3 × 3$ matrix and it satisfies $ A^T = −A$. Prove that $\det(A)= 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

I think it may relate to the space?
$A^T = -A$  can prove the column space is equal to the row space.

How to prove the $\det(A)$?

Comment: det (A) and det(A^T) are same.

Comment: What tells you the following equation $\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^3\det(A)=-\det(A)$?

Answer (score 2):

$det(A^T) =det(A) $

$det(cA) =c^n det(A) $ (determinant is linear in each row and each column)

$det(A^T) =det(-A) $

$\implies det(A) =(-1) ^n  det(A) $

If the order of the matrix $(n) $ is odd . Then,

$det(A) =-det(A) $

And, $det(A) =0$ [ provided the scalar field is not of characteristics $ 2$]

If the order of the matrix is even, then nothing can be said.

For an example,

$A= \begin {bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

Then, $A^T=-A$ and $det(A) = 1$

Alternative:

$det(A) =\text{ product of the eigen values} $

If order of $A$ is $ n=odd$, then the characteristics equation of $A$ is a polynomial of odd degree.

Any polynomial of odd degree must have a real root.

i.e any matrix of odd order has a real eigen value.

Eigen value of a skew-symmetric matrix is either $ 0$ or complex numbers.

Hence, $det(A) =0$

Answer (score 0):

You have, by using properties of the determinant
$$
-\det(A)=(-1)^3\det(A)=\det(-A)=\det(A^T)=\det(A)
$$
Hence $\det(A)=0$.
Here I have used
$$
\det(-A)=\det(-I_nA)=\det(-I_n)\det(A)=(-1)^n \det(A),
$$ where $I_n$ denotes the $n \times n$ unit matrix as well as $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$.